# C++ compilation shenanigans with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, g++

I'm currently faced with an odd problem and I would like to find documentation about why it happens and how to prevent it.

To put it simple, I'm developing a framework using dynamically loaded libraries, and this is what happens:

> ```
> void function()
> {
>   Object* object = new Object();
>
>   call_dynamic_library(object);  
> }
>
> // Dynamic library source:
> void dynamic_library_callback(Object* object)
> {
>   // The following would crash:
>   object->method();
>   // While the following would work:
>   object = new Object();
>   object->method();
> }
> ```

The pointers are of course the same, no issues there, and the headers also are.

As far as my knowledge of C compilation goes, this wouldn't be weird if the two binaries were compiled with different versions of the same headers. It's not the case however.

I mostly meet these issues while using virtual pure methods and templates.
I would like to learn more about what might cause the compiler to compile these objects two different ways even though it's based on the same headers.

Comment: It likely has something to do with your build environment. Could you come up with an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) and post it together with the Makefile?

Comment: Are you sure the two use the same virtual memory space? (if you pass the object across executables, this isn't weird at all)

Comment: versions of run time for both executable and dynamic library must be same

Comment: versions of the compiler for both executable and dynamic library must also be the same.